# How to rewrite a url in lighttpd?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, lighttpd

I am using lighttpd Is this possible to rewrite a URL internally.

`http://10.78.162.12/getSwVersion` to `http://10.78.162.12/getSwVersion.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Ofcourse it is possible. Just define a redirect.

This Doc will help you to do that

```
http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite
```